# Create Custom Game against Bot with new LoL Launcher? (Pre-Season 7)

Tags: league-of-legends

I like to try out wierd builds in customs against bot's first instead heading straight into a game and play like a troll.

But with the new Launcher, I can't find the option to add Bots to a custom game:

[image: launcher picture]

Am I missing something or have they removed this option?

Comment: [Check out this post](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/231536768).  One of the questions is "I can't select PVP or Co-op VS. AI Game Modes."  The answer: Restarting the client should take care of this.  See if that works?  I'm sure you tried this already though.  What client are you using (alpha, beta, etc.)?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that bots are not available using the beta client at this time. They will be added eventually though.

Comment: @TimmyJim: I'm using the beta client. A restart didn't work.

Comment: @MageXy: Hm, that sucks. I hope they will add it again soon?

Comment: It looks like they are looking to add the AI feature eventually as Mage Xy said.  As it is though, it seems like its not possible currently.   I've found that their forums seems to have many posts about this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the client is still only in Beta, not all features are currently available.

*But* this [has been officially commented on](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/alpha-client-discussion/Lubh1fPG-updated-client-known-issues?comment=001100000000) and it is coming soon:

> We'll be adding the bots back into custom games with the next patch.